# Error concatenating specific sheet from multiple workbooks into one df

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to separate out a specific sheet from about 300 excel workbooks and combine them into a single dataframe.

I have tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 100, "display.max_columns", 100)
allexcelfiles = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\LELI Laptop 5\Desktop\DTP1\*.xlsx")
cefdf = []

for ExcelFile in allexcelfiles:
    wb = load_workbook(ExcelFile)
    for sheet in wb:
        list_of_sheetnames = [sheet for sheet in wb.sheetnames if "SAR" in sheet]
        df = pd.read_excel(ExcelFile, sheet_name = list_of_sheetnames, nrows = 24)
        cefdf.append(df)
df = pd.concat(cefdf)
```

From which I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

I then tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(ExcelFile, sheet_name = list_of_sheetnames, nrows = 24))
```

From which I get this error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concat dictonary of DataFrames, reason is because multiple sheetnames in `list_of_sheetnames`:

```
for ExcelFile in allexcelfiles:
    wb = load_workbook(ExcelFile)

    list_of_sheetnames = [sheet for sheet in wb.sheetnames if "SAR" in sheet]
    
    dfs = pd.read_excel(ExcelFile, sheet_name = list_of_sheetnames, nrows = 24)
    cefdf.append(pd.concat(dfs))
    
df = pd.concat(cefdf)
```